# OpenCV: Rotate floor texture with warpAffine and keep tile seams adjacent to each other

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, image-processing, computational-geometry

Given a squared or rectangular floor tile texture, how to perform rotation with `warpAffine` by any angle and keep tiles to be adjacent to each other? (visually)

**original floor tile**

[image]

**EXPECTED RESULT**

**4x4 Concatenated tiles + `cv2.BORDER_WRAP`, tile seams are adjacent to each other. Texture rotated by 45 degrees counter-clockwise, but It works properly only with `n*pi/2` angles when `n` is an odd number**

[image]

**Tiles are visually disjoint, angle = 75deg**
[image]

**CODE**

```
texture = cv2.imread(ACTIVE_TEXTURE)

def concat_tile(im_list_2d):
    return cv2.vconcat([cv2.hconcat(im_list_h) for im_list_h in im_list_2d])

def rotate_texture(texture, angle=0, scale=1.0):
    print(angle)
    height, width = texture.shape[:2]
    midpoint = (width / 2, height / 2)

    rotation_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(tuple(midpoint), angle, scale)

    abs_cos = abs(rotation_mat[0, 0])
    abs_sin = abs(rotation_mat[0, 1])

    bound_w = int(height * abs_sin + width * abs_cos)
    bound_h = int(height * abs_cos + width * abs_sin)

    rotation_mat[0, 2] += bound_w / 2 - midpoint[0]
    rotation_mat[1, 2] += bound_h / 2 - midpoint[1]

    texture_rotated = cv2.warpAffine(texture, rotation_mat, (bound_w, bound_h), borderMode=cv2.BORDER_WRAP,
                                     flags=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    texture_rotated = cv2.resize(texture_rotated, (height, width), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

    return texture_rotated

rot_angle = 45
texture = rotate_texture(texture, angle=rot_angle)
tiles = [[texture for _ in range(4)] for _ in range(4)]
texture = concat_tile(tiles)

cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow('image', 600, 600)
cv2.imshow('image', texture)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me suggest a way around:

1. create tiles without rotation but make size bigger to allow crop
2. rotate entire image
3. crop to required size